# New applications open in wrong x screen in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, x11, ubuntu-9.04, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup and each has its own x screen in Ubuntu 9.04. Everything works as it should in screen 0. When I open an application in screen 1 (using any menu, e.g., Applications, Places, etc.), it opens in screen 0 instead of screen 1.

So to get an application to open in screen 1, I hit - and type the program name. This always works but is thoroughly annoying and rather inefficient. How can I make it so that new apps automatically load in the screen I am working in? Thanks!

(The release notes for 9.04 said somewhere that there was better dual monitor support, so I was hoping upgrading would have resolved this issue but it hasn't.)

Comment: I'm guessing this will be flagged, server-fault.com (6-8 weeks!)

Comment: Not really a programming question... might be appropriate for ServerFault.com once that opens, but for now please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 1):

Try asking on [the forums](http://ubuntuforums.org) - this isn't programming related and doesn't really belong here.